# Returned type should be entityManager symfony

Tags: symfony, entitymanager

I have a question regarding the specification of a function from a controller. The following function returns the service entity manager, or it should:

```
/**
 * @return EntityManager
*/
public function getEntityManager()
{
    $entityManager = $this->get('doctrine.orm.default_entity_manager');

    return $entityManager;
}
```

So, the return line said

```
Return value is expected to be '\Doctrine\Orm\EntityManager', 'object' returned.
```

Ok, I know that in specification of the function said that the returned type is object ServiceName, but how can manage this situation? I want the type to be the serviceName, not the object type. If I modify in the return specification EntityManager with object is ok, but not what I want. Anyone can help with an advice?

EDIT:

```
 /**
 * @var $entityManager EntityManager
 *
 * @return EntityManager
 */
public function getEntityManager()
{
    $entityManager = $this->get('doctrine.orm.default_entity_manager');

    return $entityManager; //still receive the warning here
}
```

Comment: Not sure I understand the question but I suppose you can try using @var to define $entityManager as being of type EntityManager.

Comment: And how do you call it? Where do you get the error?

Comment: I receive a warning in the method. @Stony

Comment: @Cerad still not working. I edited the question.

Comment: The warning is coming from your IDE?  In any event, add the line: /** @var  EntityManager */ directly before the $entityManager = ... line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the warning is shown by your **IDE** and it's not an exception thrown by PHP itself then it comes from a missing phpdoc.

In order to fix the issue (and get correct autocompletion for `$entityManager` add the `@var` docblock directly above the variable assignment inside the function.

```
/**
 * @return EntityManager
 */
public function getEntityManager()
{
    /** @var EntityManager $entityManager */
    $entityManager = $this->get('doctrine.orm.default_entity_manager');

    return $entityManager;
}
```